# Get actual username in RS connect

Tags: r, shiny, rsconnect

I have published the shiny application on RS connect. I need to print the actual username who ever is using the application. So for this, I have called `session$user` in order to get a actual username. Is it correct? Can anyone please confirm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah. That´s correct. To extract only the user you can use:

```
user <- session$user %>% str_extract("([^@]+)")
```